# Measurement with arbitrary precision

Tags: black-holes, information

I've watched a lot of Nima Arkani-Hamed lectures on YouTube and he (usually) makes the point that if you attempt to probe any distance shorter than the Planck length you have to put so much energy into such a tiny region of space you'll collapse it into a black hole.  Therefore it's not possible to talk about measurement to arbitrary precision.

After reading a bit about the black hole information paradox, it occurred to me that you can in principle probe what's going on at an arbitrary precision because even if you do collapse the region you're probing into a black hole, you can probe the resulting Hawking radiation the black hole emits.  No information is lost, assuming determinism and reversibility, correct?

Is there something wrong with my reasoning here?  btw, I am not a physicist or physics student, just an interested observer.

Answer (score -2):

I find inconsistencies with both, Nima's and your, statements.

If the Plank length **is** the **smallest** possible distance between two objects, then that means **it is impossible to make smaller** measurements. Therefore, there **is a limit** to measurement "precision" (i.e. not arbitrary), and the amount of energy required to do the measurement, has nothing to do with it!
Your statement is **irrelevant**, because measuring **radiation** has nothing to do with measuring **distance**.
 .